# Which Xcode files can I safely delete?

Tags: xcode, macos

Which of these Xcode files can I safely delete?

What are "BridgeOS Device Support", "Xcode Caches" and "Project Build Data and Indexes"?

I guess iOS Device Support are just simulators, correct?

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can safely delete the Caches (Xcode will rebuild them, which will slow down Xcode in the beginning), the Build Data and Indexes (which Xcode will also restore the next time you open the project/build the project where the data was deleted). From my understanding, iOS Device Support is for connecting your own device to the computer. Xcode will probably restore this as well, I would delete the iOS versions which you don't use. bridgeOS is for devices like the Touch Bar (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BridgeOS)).

Comment: Hey @techrisdev, thanks for your answer. But do you also know if one can delete Project archives? In the question above it's not existing but in my case it takes almost 30GB of memory space.

Comment: Oh now I see.. It's the folder for archived apps. It is even recommended to remove them, isn't it?

Answer (score 8):

"Project Build Data and Indexes" is part of Xcode derived data. So once you delete derived data then it will be release space.

Goto Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data.

[image]